# How to use struts2_jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, struts2

HI

Can somebody help me out with how to start using struts2 jquery plugin.
Can someone give me a link to a small complete project with source code..

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen these [samples](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/w/list)?

Comment: True, but that is what he is explicitly asking for: "Can someone give me a link"

Answer (score 0):

This is the google code group: https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/

This is the example application: https://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/downloads/detail?name=struts2-jquery-showcase-2.4.1.war

That example application you can see in action here: http://www.weinfreund.de/struts2-jquery-showcase/index.action